# Installing mesa-opencl-icd in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, mesa, opencl

Simply put, this library won't install using this excuse:

```
$ sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mesa-opencl-icd : Depends: libclc-r600 (>= 0.2.0+git20170330-3) but 0.2.0+git20170330-3~16.04.1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libclc-amdgcn (>= 0.2.0+git20170330-3) but 0.2.0+git20170330-3~16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that relevant packages can be installed, but have slightly different names. Possible solution here?

```
$ apt search libclc
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libclc-amdgcn/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.2.0+git20170330-3~16.04.1 all [installed]
  OpenCL C language implementation - amdgcn support

libclc-dev/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.2.0+git20170330-3~16.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
  OpenCL C language implementation - development files

libclc-ptx/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.2.0+git20170330-3~16.04.1 all [installed]
  OpenCL C language implementation - ptx support

libclc-r600/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.2.0+git20170330-3~16.04.1 all [installed]
  OpenCL C language implementation - r600 support
```

Dependencies aren't satisfied despite relevant packages were installed manually. Other similar questions suggested doing these:

```
apt update; apt upgrade; apt autoremove; apt autoclean
apt -f install
aptitude -f install
apt-get download mesa-opencl-icd; dpkg -i <*.deb>
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Neither helped or clarified the situation, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd libclc-r600=0.2.0+git20170330-3 libclc-amdgcn=0.2.0+git20170330-3` ?

Comment: Seems to be packaging bug. I reported it to [LaunchPad as bug 1743018](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1743018).

Comment: Do you have the Xorg HWE stack installed? I think mesa-opencl-icd got stuck in middle of a transition due to the Meltdown/Spectre issues.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar, this could have worked but there's only one version listed in repository.

Comment: @dobey, no, HWE is not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, from [LaunchPad bug 1743018](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1743018), bug is going to be fixed by [Timo Aaltonen (tjaalton)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1743018/comments/4) by uploading corrected package to `xenial-proposed`.

As for today one can install `mesa-opencl-icd` with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed restricted main multiverse universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mesa-opencl-icd -y
```

I can confirm that it is installing normally. So package will be uploaded to normal `-updates` soon.